# How to override styles from CSS framework (MDL) correctly

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I started a new project and decided to use MDL (https://getmdl.io) as the foundation. Now I wonder (I cannot find anything about this actually), what you would consider to be the best way to override / extend styles?

In MDL for example I have

```
.mdl-dialog {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 280px; 
}
```

and I would like to get rid of the shadow.

Obviously I will not overide / extend it in the `material.css` but I'm not if I should add an `.mdl-dialog`-entry to my `custom.css`, or if I create a new class (lets say `.my-dialog`) and add it to the DOM-Element.

Also there are DOM-Elements, that get added by JS, for those I cannot use my own classname ...

Maybe a wrapping Element with my own classname and then `.my-class .mdl-dialog`?

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way is to attach your own `css` file like `custom.css` after all other files attached to your page. And pick classes you need to change styles and override them in `custom.css`.

```
<link relation="stylesheet" href="css/styles1.css">
<link relation="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">
<link relation="stylesheet" href="css/styles3.css">
<link relation="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

If you wrap `DOM` elements and use custom classes it will just overload the browser with extra work like creating `DOM` nodes and then applying styles to them. However you can add your own classes to existing DOM elements and style them as you would like.

In `custom.css` it should be

```
.mdl-dialog {
    box-shadow: none; // add more properties that you wants to override.
}
.your-custom-class {
    background: #f00; // or whatever styles you wants to apply
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do two things.

1. Define an id in one of your root elements. For example: `<body id="mdl-custom">`. This will prioritize your selector since: Id > class > tag/pseudo-elements.

   What's the advantage of this? You won't have to worry about your element having equal priority as MDL.

   In this case, CSS file order does not matter.
2. Override the MDL classes in your custom.css just make sure to reference your file after MDL stylesheet.

   In this case, CSS file order does matter.

Now back to your mdl-dialog with no shadow you could do this:

```css
 #mdl-custom .mdl-dialog { 
    box-shadow: none;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is MDL please?

Comment: it is a minimalistic Material Design lib for web-development: https://getmdl.io/